# Canvas compositing and cut-out effect

Tags: html5-canvas

Using HTML5 Canvas, I basically have painted a colored rectangle. Now I am painting a black, wide stroke for the same rectangle but using the global composite operator Destination-In. My expected result was to have a half-width, red stroke and nothing else as painting the stroke via Destination-In should only paint the parts in the canvas where the red rectangle "hits" the stroke.. but the result is that the red rectangle's fill makes it through outside the stroke as well..

Did I missunderstand something? Here's the actual code in use:

```
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext('2d');

ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
ctx2.fillRect (10, 10, 200, 100);

ctx2.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
ctx2.lineWidth = 10;
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation='destination-in';
ctx2.strokeRect (10, 10, 200, 100);
```

EDIT: I've added a jsFiddle sample which shows what I'd expect / want and below the actual result I am getting:

http://jsfiddle.net/nLGct/1

Answer (score 0):

The result of destination-in compositing will always be:

- Some/none of your original red-filled rect will survive.
- None of your new black stroke will ever survive.

Specifically:

- The destination (the red rect) survives only where it's overlapped by the source (the black stroke).
- All non-overlapping areas are made transparent.

**Why you're getting your results:**

In canvas, a stroke is always half-inside and half-outside its path.

Therefore, the *inside-half* of your black stroke overlaps the original red fill.

So what survives destination-in is the part of the original red fill where it overlaps the inside of the black stroke.

If your black stroke is 10px wide then the inner 5 pixels overlap the red filled rect and those red pixels will survive.

Comment: I am aware of the center-aligned stroke which is fine for me. But not only do the 5px stroke inside the red rectangle survive but the rest of the rectangle's fill as well which is exactly NOT what I'd expect?

Comment: You're using Chrome aren't you?  Yep, it's a bug they haven't cleared up yet:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117675

Comment: Oh great, yet another bug in Chrome with Canvas, the same great thing like with fuzzy clipping masks..